# change order export csv action to external link Magento

Tags: magento, csv, grid, action

> Hi i need to change the export csv action in magento order grid to the
> external URL
>
> So when we select multiple orders from order grid and press
> export , it posts the order ids array to external url
>
> For this i have check the file **ordercontroller.php** in which there is
> a `
>
> function `exportCsvAction()`

`which does the csv action.

> But i am unable to find where this action is assign for the export
> function.
>
> Can you please suggest me how can i change the action to external url
> and get the posted order ids there.

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::getCsvFile(). Grid object prepares & loads the order collection and then iterate collection through _exportIterateCollection() method.

Comment: thanks for the reply , i got your point but can you please tell me how can i change the export action to custom url which is external url , and can get the selected order ids there.

Answer (score 0):

The order export actions are defined here `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::_prepareColumns`

To amend the url for "CSV" you would need to override this class using a local module and amend the following line

```
 protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
     ...
        $this->addExportType('NEW URL', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
     ... 
    }
```

Comment: HI I have try this but as i need to give external url , it attachs the external url witht he magento url ans gives 404